# How to access second member of struct via pointer?

Tags: c, struct, pointer-arithmetic

I have seen the first address of struct is simultaneously the first address of first member of that struct. Now what I would like to understand is, why I need always double pointer to move around in the struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo
{
    char *s;
    char *q;
};

int main()
{
    struct foo *p = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    char ar[] = "abcd\n";
    char ar2[] = "efgh\n";
    *(char**)p = ar;
    *(char**)((char**)p+1) = ar2; //here pointer arithmetic (char**)p+1

    printf("%s\n",p->q);
}
```

the question is, why do I need `char**` instead of simple `char*`?
What I saw in assembler is in case of simple `char*`, the arithmetic would behave like normal `char`. That is -> the expression of `(char*)p+1` would move the address `p` just by *one* byte (instead of `8` as address are 8 bytes long). But yet the type `char*` *is* address, so I don't get why the arithmetic behave like the dereference type instead (plain char -> one byte).

So the only solution for me was to add another indirection `char**`, where the pointer-arithmetic magically takes `8` as size. So why in structs is needed such bizarre conversion?

Comment: `why I need always double pointer to move around in the struct:` you don't and it makes no sense. The address of the struct is equal to the address of the first member. But _it does not mean that_ the address of second member is right behind it. It isn't. There is/may be padding. And there is `offsetof()` macro.

Comment: Don't try and treat a `struct` type like an array. If you want array-like behavior, use an array type.

Comment: @IanAbbott why not? The arrays and structs are both in stack memory. So when both got the same memory type, what makes them different? For me, structs are just improved arrays

Comment: You cannot learn C properly this way, because if you don't understand the language properly, you'll eventually invoke undefined behaviour, and the compiler is then free to output whatever assembly code it wants to in that case. Let me stress this: You *cannot* learn C by writing random crap and looking at the compiler output. It just doesn't work that way in C.

Comment: @milanHrabos If you want to treat it as an array, you could have written it as `((char**)p)[0] = ar;` `((char**)p)[1] = ar2;`. That is still bad code, but at least it is easier to read!

Comment: _What I saw in assembler is in case of simple char*_ ... _So why in structs is needed such bizarre conversion?_ They don't. Stop trying to understand basic C constructs by looking at assembler and trying to "decompile" it. See Paul's answer below. This is the third question of yours in the last 24 hours about this casting. To understand why you need `char **`, try this: `char **cp; cp = &p->s; *cp = ar; cp = &p->q; *cp = ar2;` Doing the `*(char**)((char**)p+1)` is undefined behavior because there is no guarantee that there isn't padding between `s` and `q` in the `struct`

Answer (score 7):

You are doing funny things. You should just do:

```
struct foo *p = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
char ar[] = "abcd\n";
char ar2[] = "efgh\n";
p->s = ar;
p->q = ar2;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you are doing is slightly bizarre.  It's also unsafe, since there may be padding between struct members and your address calculation may be off (that's likely not true in this particular case, but it's something to keep in mind).

As to why you need multiple pointers...

The type of `p` is `struct foo *` - it's already a pointer type.  Each of the members `s` and `q` have type `char *`.  To access the `s` or `q` members, you need to dereference `p`:

```
(*p).s = ar;    // char * == char *
(*p).q = ar2;   // char * == char *
```

So if you're trying to access the first character pointed to by `s` through `p`, you're trying to access a character through a pointer (`s`) through another pointer (`p`).  `p` does not store the address of the first character of `s`, it stores the address of the thing that stores the address of the first character of `s`.  Hence the need to cast `p` to `char **` instead of `char *`.

And at this point I must emphasize DON'T DO THIS.  You can't safely iterate through struct members using a pointer.

The `->` operator was introduced to make accessing struct members through a pointer a little less eye-stabby:

```
p->s = ar;  // equivalent to (*p).s = ar
p->q = ar2; // equivalent to (*p).q = ar2
```

Answer (score 1):

As the address of an object of a structure type is equal to the address of its first member then you could write for example

```
( void * )&p->s == ( void * )p
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo
{
    char *s;
    char *q;
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct foo *p = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    
    printf( "( void * )p == ( void * )&p->s is %s\n",
           ( void * )p == ( void * )&p->s ? "true" : "false" );
           
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
true
```

So the value of the pointer `p` is equal to the address of the data member `s`.

In other words a pointer to the data member `s` is equal to the pointer `p`.

As the type of the data member `s` is `char *` then pointer to `s` has the type `char **`.

To assign the pointed object you need to cast the pointer p of the type `struct foo *` to the type `char **`. To access the pointed object that is the data member s you have to dereference the pointer of the type `char **`.

As a result you have

```
*(char**)p = ar;
```

Now the data member `s` (that is the pointer of the type `char *`) is assigned with the address of the first element of the array `ar`.

In the second expression the left most casting is redundant

```
*(char**)((char**)p+1) = ar2;
 ^^^^^^^^
```

because the expression `(char**)p+1` is already has the type `char **`. So you could just write

```
*((char**)p+1) = ar2;
```

Comment: Is that second part valid? Because whether `q` is the same as `*((char**)p+1)` may depend on struct alignment and padding?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I looked through the C Standard and there is written a pointer after an object can point to another object if they are similarly aligned. I can not find now the reference. I need a time to find it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie There is a padding dependency, though not a practical one.

Answer (score 0):

> why do I need `char**` instead of simple `char*`

With pointer usage, the the left side of the assignment, code needs the address of the object.

```
*address_of_the_object = object
```

As the object is a `char *`, the type on the left side, the `address of the object`, needs to be type `char **`.

---

> How to access second member of struct via pointer?

Better to instead use the sensible:

```
p->q = ar2;
```

... then the convoluted:

```
//          |-- address of p->q as a char * ----|
*((char **) ((char *)p + offsetof(struct foo, q))) = ar2;
//|------------ address of p->q as a char ** ---|
```

OP's `*(char**)((char**)p+1) = ar2;` is amiss as it does the wrong pointer math and assumes no padding.

---

Convoluted approach details.

To portable find the offset within a `struct`, use `offsetof(struct foo, q)`.  It returns the byte offset and will accounts for potential padding.  Add that to a `char *` version of the `struct` address to do the proper pointer addition to form the address of `p->q`.  That sum is a `char *`, Convert to the type of the address of the object.  Lastly de-reference it on the LHS as part of the assignment.